# Finding the limit of a recursive sequence by applying the monotone convergence theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose a sequence $(a_n)$ is defined recursively, such that it is increasing and bounded.
Would it follow (by applying properties of the monotone convergence theorem) that $$\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$$
?

The problem I am trying to solve is fairly trivial if I can write the above statement, but I can't find a reference to it anywhere.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would.  Since $\{a_n\}$ is increasing and bounded, we know $\lim(a_n)$ exists.  Next, note that $\lim(a_{n+1}) = \lim(a_n)$ since the former is a subsequence of the latter.

Since these limits exist, we can apply limit arithmetic to evaluate your expression.  Assuming $\lim(a_n) \neq 0$, we get:

$$\lim \left( \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right) = \frac{\lim(a_{n+1})}{\lim(a_n)}$$

And so...

Comment: Great. Thank you. It might be a very simple question, but I just wanted to make sure I was thinking correctly.

Comment: Sure thing!  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

A consequence of this is that $a_n$ converges to some $a$.

Now of $a\neq 0$ the limit of the ratio is, thanks to the continuous mapping theorem, $1$.

If the limit is $0$ you can't say any of that. For instance:
$$
a_n = -\frac1{2^n}
\\
a_n\uparrow 0\\
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac 12\nrightarrow 0
$$